# Polymer template repeat - changing the model breaks masonry

Tags: jquery, polymer, masonry

I have a page with a bunch of cards. The cards differ in height, so I'm using selecting the shadow DOM and then calling Masonry on it  to have a stacked effect on the heights that have different cards.

The issue is that I use ajax on an interval. The ajax success data sets the model for the polymer, and then Masonry breaks. I tried setting a timeout for 100-200ms, but there's a small period where the boxes are not stacked correctly. Comparing the two variables and selectively changing things might get out of hand, but I haven't really approached that strategy.

Please advise.

Comment: we need a fiddle or link

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`<juicy-tile-list>`](https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-tile-list) - already made Custom Element, that uses bin-packing (like Masonry) in ShadowDOM and applies it to a list of any HTML nodes.

It works nice with custom and variable heights loaded asynchronously.